# Keep the object in the 3D space even when the camera is not focusing the marker

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality

When the entity spawns on the marker and I move the camera around, the entity disappears. However, I want the entity to spawn once when the camera focuses on the marker and to remain visible even when the camera loses focus. [Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-o7qr1NpeNI)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <!-- we import arjs version without NFT but with marker + location based support -->
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/dev/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
    <body style="margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;">
        <a-scene embedded arjs>
        <a-marker preset="hiro">
            <a-entity
            position="0 0 0"
            rotation="0 0 0"
            scale="0.05 0.05 0.05"
            gltf-model="../image-tracking/nft/trex/scene.gltf"
            ></a-entity>
        </a-marker>
        <a-entity camera></a-entity>
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using markers to displaty the model however you need to spawn the model in a markerless frame where the marker is displayed at a position and can be moved without markers for this you can use ar.js and aframe together.You can refer this doc - https://ar-js-org.github.io/AR.js-Docs/